# which version of sonarqube for depereciated delphi plugin?

Tags: delphi, sonarqube

I want to use the Delphi plugin for SonarQube, but apparantly it is depreciated. Hence, I would like to install an old version of SonarQube to use it. My 2 questions:
- which version of SonarQube should I use?
- where can I donwload the latest version of the Delphi plugin?

Thanks a lot and regards,

Pieter

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Have you read this http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Delphi+Plugin ?

Comment: Just because it's depreciated, doesn't mean you can't use it. It just means it's no longer supported by its contributors.

Comment: 'depreciate' and 'deprecate' are not the same word.  In this context the latter is appropriate

Comment: Hi, I've read http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Delphi+Plugin, but it doesn't sow in the Update Centre.

It's not shown in the neither plugin version matrix neither. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix

and I don't find an official downlaod link?

Comment: I was able to make it work! I didn't even had to download an old version of sonarqube (although I'm still on 4.51, soon to try on 5.x).

I followed these steps as from the part "Error loading Delphi plugin with Java 1.7" https://github.com/darianmiller/devmachine/wiki/Configure-Sonar-to-load-Delphi-language-plugin

the plugin needs to be downloaded from http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-delphi-plugin/0.2-SNAPSHOT/ (the file named sonar-delphi-plugin-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tested and is running the current version of Sonar:

Compatible with SonarQube 4.5.x and SonarQube 5.1.2
https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi

Release: https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi/releases
JAR: https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi/releases/download/0.3.3-SNAPSHOT/sonar-delphi-plugin-0.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

PS: Translated from Portuguese to English by Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here:

https://github.com/darianmiller/devmachine/wiki/Delphi-Example-Project-for-Sonar

I'm using delphi plugin 0.2 with sonar 3.5.1

Comment: I would like also to update delphi plug-in to use it with the latest sonarcube version. Anybody is interested in this project ?